# Daily question in my drupal website

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal so may be my question will be very dumb.
I want to show daily questions on my website which is build using drupal. The question is of multiple choice and the options should be displayed by default. The visitor will simply click on the ans and press submit to ans. It seems to be like a poll but i dont want to show the summary on submission instead i want to show the correct ans.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Quiz module](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) provides, well, quizzes and supports multi-choice questions. After a quiz has been fully answered, it provides various display option. It may suits your need if you use single-question quizzes.

For the quiz to be daily, you may have to add some code or use additional module to handle automatic creation, publication and de-publication of your daily quizzes.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried using quiz module with provide as block module. I created a quize with single multiple choice question, added it to the quiz. The module was coming fine but the only problem was that the question was not displayed by default instead a link was coming to start the test and details about the test was there. What i had in mind was a single question displayed by default.  
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Some time ago, I did made a (custom but re-sable) module to provide a daily qui using the Quiz module. It's not a perfect match with your need but it may be useful. As for displaying the question in a block, you'll probably need some custom code. It doesn't looks trivial given what I recall on how Quiz  handles users taking quizzes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any module that will do this out of the box, but the built-in, core module "poll" will do something terribly close.

To get the exact functionality you desire, you could simply override the template files for poll to make it so that it does not display the results upon submission. Then you could make a comment on the poll that contains the correct answer. (You can do this without allowing others the ability to comment.) This would effectively meet the given requirements.

Anyway I know its not a perfect solution, but it would give you the described requirements without too much work.

Comment: Looks great. I will try it for sure. 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Let me know if you need help figuring out the theming.

Comment: the voting module didnt work :( I am going ahead with a custom module. If all goes well then I will also contribute to drupal module repository :)